# when choose customized qcompleter dropdown list item, it does not appear in customized lineditor

Tags: qt, qcompleter

I followed this great [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tools-customcompleter.html), but when I use the arrow key to go through the customized `QCompleter` dropdown list item, the item does not appear in the customized line editor (it is highlighted in blue in the dropdown list). when I hit the enter button, the item will appear in the line editor highlighted in blue. then i have to hit the enter button again to let the editor take the item.

this is different from how `QCompleter` behaves. in `QCompleter`, when using the arrow key to go through the items, they will automatically appear in the editor without highlight. when hitting the enter button, the editor will take the item.

I spent a lot of time debugging, but couldn't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug as described here: [QTBUG-3745](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-3745). There you can also find a workaround.